# SQL syntax near, not the right use

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ERROR:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Desc='Legenday Films' WHERE ID='3'' at line 1

AT:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE conf_src SET Name='$CSRC', Desc='$CSRCD' WHERE ID='$ssID'")
```

$CSRC is the name of the source "LEGEND"

$CSRCD is the description of the source "Legendary Films"

Comment: `DESC` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql. Use backticks to escape field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a MySQL reserved word

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

which needs to be wrapped in backticks

```
`Desc`='$CSRCD'
```

Either do that or rename it to something else, such as `Description`

For the complete list, consult the MySQL.com website:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

in order to avoid using another reserved word later on.

Answer (score 3):

desc is a keyword in SQL for descending or describe, you must use backticks to quote those.

```
 UPDATE conf_src SET Name='$CSRC', `Desc`='$CSRCD' WHERE ID='$ssID'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Desc` is a reserve word and so need escaping using backtique like

```
`Desc`
```

When not sure, consider escaping all the column(s) in your select list along with table name (consider referring MySQL spec first)

```
UPDATE `conf_src` SET `Name`='$CSRC', `Desc`='$CSRCD' WHERE `ID`='$ssID'
```